# Fazer select e não retornar valores que contenham xxx

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou fazendo o seguinte select:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Nisso eu tenho o nome das tabelas, o problema é que pra cada tabela eu possuo uma tabela_AUD, ex:

```
PESSOA
PESSOA_AUD
DOCUMENTO
DOCUMENTO_AUD
```

Eu gostaria que não retornasse as tabelas que têm AUD, como posso fazer ?

Comment: Não estarás a confundir tabelas com colunas? Queres selecionar todas as colunas de uma tabela que não contenham `_AUD` certo?

Comment: Tabelas mesmo @Miguel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa usar o [`like`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/like.php) para filtrar as que tenham `AUD` e adicionando o `NOT` teremos somente as que não terminam com `AUD`.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_AUD'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.